# RavenDb Sharding reliable hash

Tags: ravendb

I'm looking for a reliable hash function for my sharding strategy.

String.GetHashCode is obviously not a way to go. I'm currently leaning towards consistent caching (not quite sure how applicable the idea of consistent caching is in case of RavenDb shrding implementation).

But it seems to me I saw once a method (or class) called ReliableHash or something like that. But I can not find it again. Or am I lunatic?

So what is the recommended way to generate hash for shards in RavenDb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like MD5 or SHA1 for consistent hashing.
But be aware of things like case sensitivity for this if you care about it.